# Subtract a textbox value from a cell

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, cell, subtraction

I have an inventory sheet.
When a researcher takes a quantity in a specific lot, the quantity is removed first from the stock quantity, the specific row of ComboBox1 in the column #8. It's okay for that part.

When a second quantity is taken and the row of the lot is not empty, I put the data in a row under but I want the quantity (textBox2) to be substract to the column #8 of the row of ComboBox1.

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Enter()

    Dim emptyRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Micrux"

    Dim iLastRow As Long, iFound As Long
    Dim rng, bEmpty As Boolean, c As Integer
    Dim Test As Boolean

    bEmpty = True

    With ws

        iLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & iLastRow + 1).Find(ComboBox1.Value, _
          After:=.Range("A" & iLastRow + 1), _
          LookIn:=xlValues, _
          lookat:=xlWhole, _
          searchorder:=xlByRows, _
          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

        Test = (TextBox2.Text) > ws.Cells(iLastRow, 8)

        If Test = True Then
            MsgBox "Not enough quantity in stock!"

        Else

            If rng Is Nothing Then
                iFound = iLastRow + 1

            Else
                iFound = rng.Row

                For c = 4 To 7
                    If Len(.Cells(iFound, c)) > 0 Then bEmpty = False
                Next

                If bEmpty = False Then
                    iFound = iFound + 1
                    .Cells(iFound, 1).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown

                    .Cells(iFound, 7).Value = TextBox2.Text
                    .Cells(iFound, 6).Value = TextBox3.Text
                    .Cells(iFound, 5).Value = ComboBox2.Value
                    .Cells(iFound, 4).Value = TextBox1.Text

                Else
                    .Cells(iFound, 7).Value = TextBox2.Text
                    .Cells(iFound, 6).Value = TextBox3.Text
                    .Cells(iFound, 5).Value = ComboBox2.Value
                    .Cells(iFound, 4).Value = TextBox1.Text
                End If

            End If

        End If

    End With

    Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: I would look at using iFound perhaps `.Cells(iFound-1, 8).Value = ComboBox2.Value=.Cells(iFound-1, 8).Value - ComboBox2.Value` the -1 I think you'll also need to work out as this will increase

Comment: Hi Nathan_Sav,
this is not working, it appears that it's not a valid formulation.
I'm also experiencing some problem with my message error, it appears all the time, I don't understand it works when all the row are fill but not anymore when I clear the content to make other test...
Did I forget to mention that I'm relatively new in programmation? 

Comment: I did say you'll need to play with it.  Use Step through debugging to check your code, see what the values are.

Comment: It now works with that code
 ws.Cells(iFound - 1, 8).Value = ws.Cells(iFound - 1, 8).Value - TextBox2.Value
Thanks for the help Nathan_Sav!!